# GKE: Service account for Config Connector lacks permissions

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gcp-config-connector

I'm attempting to get Config Connector up and running on my GKE project and am following [this getting started guide.](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/how-to/getting-started)

So far I have enabled the appropriate APIs:

```
> gcloud services enable cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com
```

Created my service account and added policy binding:

```
> gcloud iam service-accounts create cnrm-system
> gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding ncnrm-system@test-connector.iam.gserviceaccount.com --member="serviceAccount:test-connector.svc.id.goog[cnrm-system/cnrm-controller-manager]" --role="roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser"
> kubectl wait -n cnrm-system --for=condition=Ready pod --all
```

Annotated my namespace:

```
> kubectl annotate namespace default cnrm.cloud.google.com/project-id=test-connector
```

And then run through trying to apply the Spanner yaml in the example:

```
~ >>> kubectl describe spannerinstance spannerinstance-sample                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Name:         spannerinstance-sample
Namespace:    default
Labels:       label-one=value-one
Annotations:  cnrm.cloud.google.com/management-conflict-prevention-policy: resource
              cnrm.cloud.google.com/project-id: test-connector
API Version:  spanner.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
Kind:         SpannerInstance
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2020-09-18T18:44:41Z
  Generation:          2
  Resource Version:    5805305
  Self Link:           /apis/spanner.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1/namespaces/default/spannerinstances/spannerinstance-sample
  UID:                 
Spec:
  Config:        northamerica-northeast1-a
  Display Name:  Spanner Instance Sample
  Num Nodes:     1
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2020-09-18T18:44:41Z
    Message:               Update call failed: error fetching live state: error reading underlying resource: Error when reading or editing SpannerInstance "test-connector/spannerinstance-sample": googleapi: Error 403: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
    Reason:                UpdateFailed
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Ready
Events:
  Type     Reason        Age                      From                        Message
  ----     ------        ----                     ----                        -------
  Warning  UpdateFailed  6m41s        spannerinstance-controller  Update call failed: error fetching live state: error reading underlying resource: Error when reading or editing SpannerInstance "test-connector/spannerinstance-sample": googleapi: Error 403: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
```

I'm not really sure what's going on here, because my cnrm service account has ownership of the project my cluster is in, and I have the APIs listed in the guide enabled.

The CC pods themselves appear to be healthy:

```
~ >>> kubectl wait -n cnrm-system --for=condition=Ready pod --all                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
pod/cnrm-controller-manager-0 condition met
pod/cnrm-deletiondefender-0 condition met
pod/cnrm-resource-stats-recorder-58cb6c9fc-lf9nt condition met
pod/cnrm-webhook-manager-7658bbb9-kxp4g condition met
```

Any insight in to this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the error message you have posted, I should supposed that it might be an error in your [GKE scopes](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#accesscopesiam).

To GKE access others GCP APIs you must allow this access when creating the cluster. You can check the enabled scopes with the command:

`gcloud container clusters describe <cluster-name>` and find in the result for `oauthScopes`.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#spanner) you can see the scope's name for Cloud Spanner, you must enable the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` as minimum permission.

To verify in the GUI, you can see the permission in: `Kubernetes Engine` > `<Cluster-name>` > expand the section `permissions` and find for `Cloud Platform`

Comment: This seems like a huge failing of the documentation- I saw nothing about scopes. Also, I _think_ this is wrong. The whole point of workload identity is to federate a GSA and a KSA. the scopes for the gke cluster are for the role/service account attached to the actual GCE instances right? You dont want to give the _cluster_ this access you want to give the GSA this access. it should be the gsa making these calls not the compute service account attached to the cluster

Answer (score 1):

I was having that same error message, except it was because the node and the node pool it belonged to did not have the `GKE Metadata Server` enabled.

To check, using `kubectl`, find out which nodes the pods are on

```
kubectl get pods -n cnrm-system -o wide
```

go to the cluster in the GCP UI (easier this way), then to the nodes tab, then to the node pool that each of the `cnrm-system` pods are running on.
Check under `Security` to see if they have the `GKE Metadata Server` enabled or not. (3rd from the bottom in this picture)

[image]

What I'd found - the first few times - was that I always had 1 or 2 node pools that did not have the metadata server enabled, and whenever one of the config-connector pods ended up on that node, it'd give me that exact error.

The note in the doco about needing to enable the metadata server (or workload identity) in each node pool is hidden away in a tiny line.

It'd be nice if GCP made it possible for their pods to be steered towards a node that had a label so that we could direct it to a specific node pool that we'd created with workload identity on...

Hope that helps!